# Replacing nan values in one column with mean of same column ( not Null values of column) where other columns have certain values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Replace the missing values in the variable "s_months" and "incidents" by the respective means of the other ships that share the same type AND the same operation period.
Here "s_months" and "incidents" are two columns, having nan values, which we want to fill.

[image: DataFrame named ship]

I have tried to find means according to asked conditions. But unable to fill nan values in ship data frame. Here are means calculated, and stored as a data frame.

[image: DataFrame namd shipgroup having means calculated based on cross product of "types" and "o_periods"]

Comment: Have look at this, I hope it helps: [Handling missing values](https://www.kaggle.com/alexisbcook/missing-values)

Comment: Please show an [MCVE] so we can see how far you got.

Comment: @Joooeey I have calculated means and stored them into another DataFrame. Now, I just have to look at any row or tuple in the first DataFrame where there are nan values. Then check its "type" and "o_period".
Take values of means for that "types" and "o_periods" from the second DataFrame and fill in to the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `combine_first` to fill NaN:

[Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
>>> df
   types  o_periods  s_months  incidents
0      1          2      63.0        0.0
1      1          2    1095.0        4.0
2      1          2    3353.0       18.0
3      1          2       NaN        NaN
```

```
keys = ['types', 'o_periods']
vals = ['s_months', 'incidents']

df[vals] = df[vals].combine_first(df.groupby(keys)[vals].transform('mean'))
```

Output result:

```
>>> df
   types  o_periods     s_months  incidents
0      1          2    63.000000   0.000000
1      1          2  1095.000000   4.000000
2      1          2  3353.000000  18.000000
3      1          2  1503.666667   7.333333
```